# Mathematical interpretation of Aristotelian mechanics

Tags: physics, reference-request, ancient-greece, classical-mechanics

I am looking for books which include a mathematical interpretation of Aristotle's hypotheses about mechanics. I heard that there are a few books which interpret his mechanical ideas mathematically, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: You can find discussion of A's mechanics in some good books, like René Dugas, [A History of Mechanics](https://books.google.it/books?id=kdDDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA19) or Edoardo Benvenuto, [An Introduction to the History of Structural Mechanics](https://books.google.it/books?id=GsRRAAAAMAAJ) but you cannot find a "mathematical analysis" of it, because A's physics is not formulated in mathematical terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[De Groot's book Aristotle's Empiricism: Experience and Mechanics in the 4th Century B.C.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1930972830) puts Aristotelian mechanics in the context of mathematical developments of his time. [Rovelli's article Aristotle’s Physics: a Physicist’s Look](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4057.pdf) gives a modernized and mathematized view of Aristotelian mechanics, interpreting him generously, and availing him of an overall dynamical framework that did not emerge until Newton. Still, one can agree that in some sense and partially the classical mechanics does reduce to Aristotle's in the limit of highly resistive medium. If by "Aristotle's hypothesis" you simply mean "velocity is proportional to the force" there is some discussion of it on [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69790/interpreting-aristotles-law-of-motion-vec-f-r-vec-v), and a bit more in Rovelli's article, but still not enough to fill a book I am afraid.

In the spirit of modernization, some physicists are having even more fun with Aristotelian mechanics, [relating it to special relativity](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.0010v1.pdf), or even [quantizing it!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80562/can-we-quantize-aristotelian-physics)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, Galilei's [*Two New Sciences*](http://galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu/tns61.htm) is what you're looking for. This is as close to quantitative analysis as you'll find, because Aristotle did not quantify his observations even in form.

The entire [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=tG1bAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) contains more discussion, but in general, you can reconstruct Aristotle's arguments from his own *Physics* and *Metaphysics*, with a couple of algebraic equations, which is what I recommend. It's the most straightforward method. Writings of Huygens are recommended, as well. There isn't much detailed discussion afterwards, mostly examples selected as illustrations of theories of history of science.